# How to run docker via docker-compose up in ecs2 fargate

Tags: docker, docker-compose, aws-fargate

I need to add extra_hosts to my container.
Here's the docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  nodejs:
    extra_hosts:
      - "<name here>:<ip here>"
      - "<name here>:<ip here>"
    dns:
      - <ip here>
      - <ip here>
      - <ip here>
    network_mode: 'host'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

I am starting container locally and logging /etc/hosts in the app.
If I start the container with `docker-compose up`, I can see extra hosts added in to /etc/hosts

If I start container via `docker run <container>` host file is not changed.
Same happens on AWS deployment on EC2 Fargate.

Is there a way to start container in Fargate with `docker-compose up` ?
Or any other solutaion which will start container on fargate according docker-compose file?

Thanks.

Comment: ECS, EKS, or EC2?  Can you set up Route 53 to provide a consistent DNS setup, instead of using a fragile `/etc/hosts` setup?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the shown docker-compose file you indeed add additional hosts in the `/etc/hosts` file because of the `extra_hosts` entry in your yaml file.

To run the container with `docker-run` you should add the `--add-host`[1] flags to the command.

So your command would become:

```
docker-run <container> --add-host "<name here>:<ip here>" --add-host "<name here>:<ip here>"
```

[1] https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts